# Why Generalized Least Squares?

Tags: regression, linear, weighted-regression, generalized-least-squares

So it is often advise to use Generalized Least Squares when we have a regression model with non-spherical(i.e. heteroskedastic or autocorrelated) errors. We do so by doing a weighted regression
$$
(y-x\hat\beta)^TW(y-x\hat\beta)
$$
with $W = \Sigma^{-1} =  Cov(\epsilon)^{-1}$, the inverse of the covariance matrix of errors.

The variance of the estimated $\hat\beta$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var(\hat\beta_{GLS})&=(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TW\Sigma W^TX(X^TW^TX)^{-1}\\
&=(X^TWX)^{-1}=(X^T\Sigma^{-1} W)^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

To do GLS, we must know $\Sigma$. But if we already know $\Sigma$, why can't we just do regular OLS, and calculate $Var(\hat\beta)$ as
$$
Var(\hat\beta)=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\Sigma X(X^TX)
$$
? Is it because $Var(\hat\beta_{GLS})$ is smaller?

Another question I've always had is that for OLS, $\beta$ is estimated as :
$$
\hat\beta_{OLS}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$
. For GLS or WLS, the $\hat\beta$ is estimated as
$$
\hat\beta_{GLS} = (X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy
$$
, which is unbiased for non-spherical error. Yet, we are told that **$\hat\beta_{OLS}$ is also an unbiased estimator** of $\beta$, even with non-spherical errors. Does that mean
$(X^TWX)^{-1}X^TWy$ simplifies to $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed do regular OLS and compute the variance of the estimator (and that estimator will be unbiased and consistent).

But, GLS will be a more efficient estimator that has a lower variance of the sampling distribution (in fact out of all unbiased linear estimators, it will be the estimator with the least possible variance).

---

Example

Let us estimate $\mu$ with the following variables $$X_k \sim N\left(\mu, \sigma^2 \cdot k\right)$$

Then

$$\begin{array}{}
\hat\mu_\text{OLS}& =&\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n {X_k} &\sim& N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\cdot{\frac{1+1/n}{2}}\right)\\
\hat\mu_\text{GLS}& =&\frac{1}{H_{n,0.5}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} {X_k} &\sim& N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\cdot{\frac{n}{(H_{n,0.5})^2}}\right)
\end{array}$$

where $H_{n,0.5} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^{0.5}}$

The variance of the GLS estimator is smaller than the variance of the OLS estimator. So if you can reasonably guess the covariance matrix of the error distribution $\Sigma$ this may be beneficial.

[image: example comparison OLS and GLS]

Comment: That makes sense. What about the estimate of coefficient themselves? Is $\hat\beta_{OLS} = \hat\beta_{GLS}$? If not, how can both be unbiased estimators?

Comment: GLS estimates $\Sigma$.  You just need to tell GLS the assumed correlation pattern (e.g., AR(1)) in order for it to estimate $\Sigma$.

Comment: @wwyws - if the estimates were always the same, neither would be better than the other.  They can both be unbiased if both their *expected* values are the same (and equal to the true parameter); with each individual sample, though, their *calculated* values can still be different, as long as the differences have an *expected* value equal to zero.

Comment: @wwyws the example shows how the estimates are different. It is due to the different coefficients in the sum. But because the coefficients both sum up to 1, you get that the estimates have the expectation value $\mu$ and are unbiased.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus - You can not do OLS for heteroscedastic dataset in order to get Best Linear Unbiased Estimation -- it is errorness way for modelling your dependency.

Comment: GLMs is OK for non-normally distributed data -- you should create hypothesis about the [distribution](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/sspdocs/sspum/2.3/distribution-fitting-analysis/distribution-fitting-and-parameter-estimation) of your data first, as assumption,. To determine which distribution (normal, exponential, or gamma) fits the dataset most accurately, you can use a goodness-of-fit test., or [chi-square test](https://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/2284/mod_resource/content/0/ocw_iam530/9.DISTRIBUTION%20FITTING.pdf)

Comment: if with GLS *you just mean WLS - then yes, I fully agree, that it's OK for heteroscedastic data... if you see no other pattern in residuals plot after modelling dependency/AR

Comment: @JeeyCi Is there something you disagree with? Where I am saying that you can do OLS (in the first sentence), I am not saying that this leads to a best linear unbiased estimator.

Comment: "Where I am saying that you can do OLS (**in the first sentence**)".. for heteroscedastic  data (wanted in OP) you can do only WLS, your first sentence is misleading for correct statistical inference, though you can assume whatever you like, just not presenting it like real opportunity for valid stat. conclusions

Comment: @JeeyCi where does the question state that it is about statistical inference? Where do I say that I speak about inference? (I am changing slightly that first sentence, since unbiased does not clearly refer to the estimator, and might be interpreted as referring to the variance)

Comment: where? - !! **stats**.stackexchange.com - no more comments ...

Comment: @JeeyCi I don't understand your point. How are your remarks related to this question and answer to it? If you don't want to explain that further then why not delete the comments? I am saying that one can do OLS in the first sentence, but I am not saying that you can do this *„in order to get Best Linear Unbiased Estimation”*. And the question is also not asking about inference but about the unbiasedness of OLS.

Comment: Still, even if you would apply inference, then this can also be done when one performs OLS, as long as one makes sure that the variance of the estimators are estimated with the correct assumptions about the error distribution. OLS is only the method to compute the estimate. It is not the method to compute the variance of the estimate.